# Android: Change in xml layout not reflected in R.java

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner in android development. I try to overwrite the content in my xml layout (main_activity.xml) that generated by gui builder tool with some tutorial content from internet for that xml layout. But this change not reflected in R.java so I cannot call the variable declaration (for example a button) with findViewByID(R.id.xxxx). How to solve this?

Comment: check if you have errors in resources fix it clean and build check if you have `import andorid.R.` if so remove it

Comment: Remember to save your project.

Comment: @Raghunandan Sory, I'm very beginner in this field, I mean in R.java every variable declaration asignned to some hex value. But I don't know how to create a value for my variable whereas that variable not declared in xml layout.

Comment: @Zohra Khan: I already save that file. But the change not reflected in R.java. When I open the code with android default xml editor there are no gui editor, juts  xml code.

Comment: Not declared in xml? Do you mean it is declared programmatically?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, try Project->Clean.

Comment: @Adam:  Not, it is declared with xml layout 
(you can see in this tutorial: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/) What I mean was when I replace the content of  main_activity.xml that contain some textfield with text string hello world with the xml code from that tutorial, and I try to open that with xml editor in eclipse, there are no gui builder appear, just text editor, then when I save that change, the change not reflected in R.java, because there are no GUI builder.

Comment: @Raghunandan: If I remove import for R.java, then how I call variable declaration from layout xml??  for example a button declared in that file?

Comment: @ajb: I was clean that project and there still variable artifact from previous layout....

Comment: @pisang_ijo `import yourpackagename.R;`

Answer (score 0):

if you just changed the `main_activity.xml`, first be sure of don´t have any errors inside your  `/res` folder, open the "`problems`" window in eclipse, if there are any issues in any of the .xml files, `R.java` will not be generated.
I think most of the problems that can´t be generated are related to errors inside `/res` folder.

Then will be enough with `Project` -> `Clean`